# Why does only some laravel routes return model attributes?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, model

i´m studying laravel but having some doubts..

**Controller**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\ItemNfe;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ItensNfeController extends Controller
{
public function edit($id,ItemNfe $itemNfe)
    {
        //i don´t want to have to make this select below
        //$itemNfe = DB::table('itens_nfe')->where('id_itemnfe',$id)->get();

        // dd($itemNfe); this dd() returns model attributes on few of my controllers only
        return view...
    }...
```

**Model:** (note i´m not using laravel convention but it´s informed)

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ItemNfe extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'itens_nfe';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id_itemnfe';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id_itemnfe','fk_venda', 'fk_produto'...
    ];

    public function nfe()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Nfe'); //this is one diference among others models, but apparently doesn´t affects when i tested without this code.
    }
}
```

The route i´m using is the same for everyone.. "resource routes"
At the first 2, i have the attributes returning, but not at the last one...

```
    Route::resource('/usuarios', 'UsuariosController');
    Route::resource('/nfes', 'NfesController');
    Route::resource('/itensnfe', 'ItensNfeController');
```

**The Url used is:**
`https://localhost/erpoverweb/public/itensnfe/1/edit`

If needing more code please tell me... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to manually search the database for the entry, you can use Laravel Container do perform a Dependency Injection. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/container#introduction

```
public function edit(ItemNfe $itemNfe)
{
    // Returns the model, and you didn't need to manually searched.
    // Laravel automaticly injects this for you.
    dd($itemNfe);
}
```

Comment: I did it before, but it works in parts... only at that controller i receive an empty attributes array... and i didn´t figure out why.

Comment: You have to match the route param with the controller param.

Route::get('/item/{item}')

public function getItem(Item $item) { }

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for **Route Model Binding** (implicit at that). This requires that the route parameter name and the name of the parameter of the method signature for that route match.

```
public function edit(ItemNfe $itensnfe)
```

The resource route with resource name 'itensnfe' should make the parameter 'itensnfe'.

If you don't make these match you will just end up with Dependency Injection which would inject a new model instance.

[Laravel 7.x Docs - Routing - Route Model Binding - Implicit Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#implicit-binding)